# Refresh & Clear JQuery Chosen plugin dynamically in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am trying to dynamically populate the jquery chosen plugin both with "optgroup" and "option". I therefore have nested ajax requests and forloops:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetCat", "MController"))',
      data: { ID: metada },
      success: function (data) {
           var categories = data.split(",");

       for (i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
                   url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetCat", "MController"))',
                   data: { ID: cetada },
                   success: function (data) {
                        $("#picker").append("<optgroup label='" + categories[i] + "'>");
                        var subcategories = data.split(",");

                        for (i = 0; i < subcategories.length; i++) {
                          $("#picker").append("<option value='"+subcategories[i]+"'>" + subcategories[i] + "</option>")
                        }
                        $("#picker").append("</optgroup>");

                   }
         });        
    }
    $("#picker").trigger('chosen:updated');
}
     });
```

Currently when I run the above the chosen select is empty and no options or optgroups are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use [promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) for this:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    promises.push(
        (function(innerI){
            return $.ajax({
                url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetCat", "MController"))',
                data: { ID: cetada },
                success: function (data) {
                    var optgroup = $('<optgroup>').attr('label', categories[innerI]);
                    var subcategories = data.split(",");
                    for (var i = 0; i < subcategories.length; i++) {
                        var option = $('<option>').val(subcategories[i]).text(subcategories[i]);
                        optgroup.append(option);
                    }
                    $("#picker").append(optgroup);
                }
            });
        })(i)); // unbind i to make closure work.
}
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    $("#picker").trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

#### UPDATE1:

I missed closures on first look, now th code is updated.

#### UPDATE2:

Rewrote working with tags inside success callback of ajax request.

#### UPDATE3:

Here is simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2h446/2/), I've commented some non-important code to show how it works.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above: the first time when I click on the chosen dropdown its empty, the second time its populated only with options and not optgroups: does not style the optgroups.

Comment: I am getting this html from above: <optgroup label="undefined"></optgroup>

<option value="Abandoned carsAbandoned cars"></option>

<optgroup label="Animal-related problems"></optgroup>

<option value="Abandoned carsFalse calls to emergency services"

Comment: Now it does not work at all: nothing is being populated. At before the problem was categories was losing its status/values after the subcategories ajax call and was empty.

Comment: See for errors in your code. I've added jsfiddle with my code - it works.